# Print current html page in next page onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to print current html page in new page using button attribute 'onclick()' I used the follwing

```js
javascript
function printPartOfPage(elementId)
{
 var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
 var windowUrl = 'P2P Money Transfer';
 var uniqueName = new Date();
 var windowName = 'P2P Money Transfer  -' + uniqueName.getTime();

 var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');

 printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
 printWindow.document.close();
 printWindow.focus();
 printWindow.print();
 printWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="JavaScript:printPartOfPage('printDiv');" >
```

but problem is there are no style implemented,so I need current entire html page to transfer to method and write it using document.write() which has all styles in it.

Comment: is jquery allowed here?

Comment: @CerlinBoss javascript/jquery doesn't matter only intendent output is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [printThis](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis) jquery library to achieve your goal.

With this library you can print some part of the page (example a div) and decide to use css of the page or an external css to add as parameter.
Here a list of parameters

```
$("#mySelector").printThis({
 *      debug: false,               * show the iframe for debugging
 *      importCSS: true,            * import page CSS
 *      importStyle: false,         * import style tags
 *      printContainer: true,       * grab outer container as well as the contents of the selector
 *      loadCSS: "path/to/my.css",  * path to additional css file - us an array [] for multiple
 *      pageTitle: "",              * add title to print page
 *      removeInline: false,        * remove all inline styles from print elements
 *      printDelay: 333,            * variable print delay
 *      header: null,               * prefix to html
 *      formValues: true            * preserve input/form values
 *  });
```

As you can see there is the property `importStyle` and if you set it to true the script load the same scripts of the page. You can also load an external css with the property `loadCSS`.

I have used it and it works well.

look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dJjMz/2/) fiddle for an example

Comment: may i know how to call function using html

Comment: I have added a fiddle as example

Comment: why not? maybe an alert at the bottom of the page is asking you if you want open the popup window. I've tested it now

Comment: I tried but sorry to say it does not work for me, even i tried copying the code and locally but it does not work.

Comment: Just check for other examples about that library... I use it in my projects and works well